R dplyr function ceases to work when using map to iterate over vector of column names
I've got a large dataset and want to apply a custom function over each of the columns.
I've written the function and it works when applied as a one-off on one column of the target dataset.
However, when I try to use purrr::map, then the custom function throws an error about halfway through the function.
There's a select statement which references the column I want to use and this throws an error saying can't reference columns that don't exist; Column `var1` doesn't exist.
I've put a reproducible example below. The actual data is 1,000s of columns wide.
Ultimately, I want to get an output where the relative risk of the outcome variable is listed against each column in the dataset:



column_name
rr_0
rr_1




var1
1
1.17


var2
1
1.03


var3
...
...



Reproducible example
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
set.seed(1)
# sample dataset
test_dat <- data.frame(var1 = rbinom(n = 10, size = 1, prob = 0.3), 
                       var2 = rbinom(n = 10, size = 1, prob = 0.1),
                       var3 = rbinom(n = 10, size = 1, prob = 0.4),
                       outcome = rbinom(n = 10, size = 1, prob = 0.3))
test_dat

# get names of columns to iterate
over_vec <- names(test_dat)
over_vec <- over_vec[!(over_vec %in% c("outcome"))]
over_vec

# function I want to use
test_fun <- function(code, dataset){
  dataset <- dataset %>% 
    group_by({{code}}) %>% 
    summarise(n = n(), n_out = sum(outcome)) %>% 
    mutate(risk = n_out/n * 100, 
           rr = risk / risk[row_number() == 1])  %>%
    dplyr::select({{code}}, rr) %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = {{code}}, values_from = rr)
  return(dataset)
}

# works for one column
test_fun(code = var1, dataset = test_dat)

# fails when iterated with purrr::map
output <- over_vec %>% 
  map(.x = ., .f = test_fun, dataset = test_dat)
output


You are passing the column names as a vector of strings, but your function is written to accept a bare symbol as the first argument - note that you are calling it successfully with code = var1, not as code = "var1".
You could just convert over_vec to a list of symbols:
over_vec %>% 
  lapply(as.symbol) %>%
  map(.x = ., .f = test_fun, dataset = test_dat)
#> [[1]]
#> # A tibble: 1 x 2
#>     `0`   `1`
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1  1.17
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> # A tibble: 1 x 2
#>     `0`   `1`
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     0
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> # A tibble: 1 x 2
#>     `0`   `1`
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1  1.17


Thanks, that works. I'm confused though, why does the group_by() work, but the select part of the function doesn't?

The group_by part doesn't work. It doesn't throw an error, but neither does it do what you think it is doing. To see this, try running the code iris %>% group_by("foo"). There is no error, but a new column is created called "foo" (not foo), which contains only the string "foo". Conversely, if you call iris %>% group_by(foo) you get a "column foo not found" error. The reason for this is that group_by can create new columns on the fly, such as iris %>% group_by(Spec = substr(Species, 1, 3)). A string being passed gets evaluated as a new column and given a default name.
